# if condition not working in jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Here I am using an choice parameters plugin, i need to build the jobs as per the parameter values in choices
for Example:

```
 CHOICE PARAMETER
 NAME: Project
 VALUE:   Job1
           Job2
```

Here Each parameter value has 6 jobs builds need to run in parallel.

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
node('') {
if (Project == 'Job1'){
    stages ('Parallel-A'){
        parallel(firstTask: {
            stage ('Parallel-test1'){
            build job: 'test1'
    }
}, secondTask: {
        stage ('Parallel-test2'){
        build job: 'test2'
    }
})
}
}
if (Project =='Job2'){
    stages ('Parallel-B'){
        parallel(firstTask: {
            stage ('Parallel-test3'){
            build job: 'test3'
    }
}, secondTask: {
    stage ('Parallel-test4'){
    build job: 'test4'
    }
})
}
}
}
```

but its not working here, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm no more used to the old pipeline syntax, but I think you should use `params.Project`, otherwise the parameters are usually accessible as environment variables

Comment: please not that params are case sensitive where as env is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$Project` 
As it was set as parameter, "$" shall be added before the variable.